# Spring MVC: how to require POST parameters in the request body and ignore query string parameters?

Tags: security, authentication, spring-mvc

I have a simple controller that provides an authentication web service.  It accepts username and password as POST parameters and returns a JSON result.  Because password is being submitted, I don't want to encourage anyone to submit it on the query string.  I want to enforce that it only be accepted in the request body.  This will ensure ssl encryption of the posted value.  How do I accomplish that in Sping MVC?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleAuthenticateGet(
            @RequestParam(value = PRAConstants.USERNAME) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = PRAConstants.PASSWORD) String password)
    {
        boolean authSuccess = LDAPUtil.authenticateUser(username, password);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"result\":" + authSuccess + "}", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look in the HTTP request to find the actual full URL and verify no parameters

Comment: @LeeMeador: that works for me.  i posted that as a solution - inspecting the request.getQueryString().  thanks!

Comment: @Jaffadog, did you find any idiomatic way of doing it instead of using StringUtils?

Answer (score 0):

Per Lee Meador, I've added this:

```
boolean authSuccess = false;
// if password is passed on the query string, then always return false. otherwise, go ahead and check with ldap
if ( !StringUtils.contains(request.getQueryString(), PRAConstants.PASSWORD) )
{
    authSuccess = LDAPUtil.authenticateUser(username, password);
}
```

that works for me...